# Cannot view SQLite Tables

Tags: database, sqlite

I have created a SQLite database . After quiting CMD, I issue .tables command but I can’t see the tables. When I try to query the tables, it returns no such  table exists even though the database is showing . Please help am a beginner . Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friends . It failed because I didn’t add the .db extension . When added everything works fine . I am leaving this here just in case another person makes the same mistake